# Amazon Product API: Redirect to URL/ send parameter (postback) after Amazon sale

Tags: url, postback, amazon-product-api, vacuum

Using Amazon associates I advertise a link. How do I get a parameter back after a sale has been made? (cid)

I want to redirect to a url after the conversion, or to shoot a parameter back to my site, so I can see which clicks converted. How do I do that? I look everywhere in Amazon's Associate (affiliate) program, but couldn't find anything. Can I do this there?

Or perhaps I need to use Amazon's Product Advertising API? I couldn't find anything about that there, only about displaying products, not about what happens *after* the sale. I have to be able to record this. I found the `vacuum` gem for Rails, but it is not in the examples.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Additional tracking can be done by the additional associate IDs manually created in your Amazon account. But there is no postback available for their servers.